# Django Admin showing Object - not working with __unicode__ OR __str__

Tags: python, django, postgresql

my Django admin panel is showing `object` instead of `self.name` of the object.

I went through several similar questions here yet couldn't seem to resolve this issue. `__unicode__` and `__str__` bear the same results, both for books and for authors. I've changed those lines and added new authors/books in every change but no change.

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('Book name', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=False, null=False)
    contents = models.TextField('Contents', blank=False, null=False)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

> I used both **unicode** & **str** interchangeably, same result.

Here are the screenshots of the admin panel by menu/action.

> 1st screen

[image: 1st screen]

> Author List

[image: Author List]

> Single Author

[image: Single Author]

Comment: Python defines the body of a class/function through indentation, it isn't just for code readability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect. You need to indent the code to make it a method of your model. It should be:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If you are using Python 3, use [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str). If you are using Python 2, use `__unicode__`, or decorate your class with the `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator. After changing the code, make sure you restart the server so that code changes take effect.

Comment: My god you've helped so much, these indents will be the end of me, I MISS PHP already.